# convert JSON format to Java format

Tags: java, json

Need to achieve this JSON format of output as below using JAVA

```
[['2008-09-30 4:00PM',4], ['2008-10-30 4:00PM',6.5], ['2008-11-30 4:00PM',5.7], ['2008-12-30 4:00PM',9], ['2009-01-30 4:00PM',8.2]]
```

Cant use a list as the internal elements belong to string and integers (generics doesnt allow that).
Tried JsonObject of Gson also, it creates a map rather than a List.

http://jsfiddle.net/6heredzz/3/

Please help

Comment: You should use a map...

Comment: Map gives me the incorrect format as : [{2012-02-02 02:02:00.0=1, 2014-01-01 00:00:00.0=12}, {2012-02-02 02:02:00.0=2, 2014-01-01 00:00:00.0=12}, {2015-01-01 00:00:00.0=13}, {2015-01-01 00:00:00.0=13}, {2012-02-02 02:02:00.0=1, 2014-01-01 00:00:00.0=12}, {2012-02-02 02:02:00.0=2, 2014-01-01 00:00:00.0=12}]

Comment: this aint a valid json !

Comment: youre right its not a valid JSON. But can i achieve this using javascript as its needed for JqPlot graphs

Comment: First go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes to learn.  Then observe that a JSON "object" is a pretty good match for a Java Map, and a JSON "array" is a pretty good match for a Java List.  (What you have above is an array of arrays, and GSON (among many) should be able to build it with no difficulty, from a List of Lists.)

Comment: @brso05 - Why should he use a Map when the JSON is an array of arrays?  (Granted, the JSON layout is a bit weird, but I've seen much weirder.)

Comment: (The original JSON above is invalid in only one sense -- the `'` character was used where `"` is required.  Some JSON kits can be told to tolerate this.)

Comment: @HotLicks A map is what he wants he has date(key) and number(value) this is perfect for a map not a list...in this case if you look at the data he is using "an array of arrays" would be well represented as a map each date is a key unique field and each number is a value...

Comment: @brso05 - The structure in his sample is an array of arrays -- no Maps required.

Comment: @HotLicks how are you going to create his structure with a list of lists that doesn't make any sense.  Don't look at his structure look at his data.  Yes you could create a list of lists or a multi-dimensional array but this doesn't make any sense when his data is better represented with a map. He has key-value pairs what do maps hold...key value pairs

Comment: In java you should not represent this as a list of lists or a multi-dimensional array you want a map.

Comment: @HotLicks not to mention he has different data types integer and string so this couldn't be represented by a list of lists or a multidimensional array unless he converted everything to the same data type ie. all strings so this wouldn't work with a list or array map is what he wants...

Comment: @brso05 - He can have a list of Object and use Integer, Double, BigDecimal, etc.  Only a problem if you insist on tightly coded generics.

Comment: @HotLicks yes he could do that you are correct but why do that when his data matches a Map already easy to retrieve data by key why do the work of creating additional classes when Map is already there so might as well use it also his data fits a map better than doing what you suggested...

Comment: @HotLicks you meant create a class with String and int inside right because you can't have a list of 2 different data types that won't work `List<List<String>>` example list of list of strings but then he would have to convert everything to string what you are saying won't work unless you create a custom class like `List<MyCustomClass>`...bottom line he should use a Map in Java to represent his data

Comment: @brso05 - I meant `List<List<Object>>` -- Very simple.  There is no need to force every JSON structure to map to a POJO.

Comment: @HotLicks why would he do that when he could use a map?

Comment: @brso05 - Ask him why he wants an array of array.

Comment: @HotLicks now he would have to cast the objects properly when he retrieves them. It doesn't make sense in this case...

Comment: @brso05 -- Oh, horror or horrors!!  One would have to use a ***cast***!!  (What is wrong with using casts??)

Comment: @HotLicks array of array is just a multi-dimensional array but javascript is a very different language than java what works in javascript doesn't necessarily translate directly to Java...in this case it doesn't...

Comment: @HotLicks nothing is wrong with using a cast but you shouldn't be using it how you want to use it this is not good programming practice...

Comment: @HotLicks Javascript != Java.

Comment: @brso05 - So who defines "good programming practice"??  I've seen the monstrosities created by people trying to map stuff to POJOs or generics vs just doing the straight-forward thing.  I'll stick with "poor" programming practices, thank you.

Comment: @brso05 - Nowhere did I mention Javascript.  It was only mentioned once in this thread, until you brought it up again.

Comment: var line1=[['2012-02-02 02:02:00.0',4], ['2014-01-01 00:00:00.0',6.5], ['2012-02-02 02:02:00.0',5.7], ['2015-01-01 00:00:00.0',9], ['2015-01-01 00:00:00.0',8.2]];
   var line2=[['2012-02-02 02:02:00.0',7], ['2014-01-01 00:00:00.0',9], ['2012-02-02 02:02:00.0',11], ['2015-01-01 00:00:00.0',19], ['2015-01-01 00:00:00.0',8]];
JQplot wants the data that way. Anyways thanks for the help (and downvotes), will do it via a shitty string approach

Comment: @HotLicks I'm not sure why you keep fighting for the incorrect solution this data should be represented as a Map in Java.  This is my last comment.

Comment: @AlCoder - I suspect your problem is that you're letting the tool do the data mapping rather than doing it yourself. Don't tell the tool that you have a date -- just pass it the String date.

Comment: I am passing it the string date, just cant create the damn data structure it requires (which is not even JSON)...example of the jqplot graph is here http://jsfiddle.net/6heredzz/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Java's a little rusty, but something like:

```
List<List<Object>> mainList = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();
for (--each inner list entry--) {
    List<Object> innerList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    String dateString = SomeDateFormatter.formatDate(theDate, "yyyy-MM-dd h:mmA");
    innerList.add(dateString);
    BigDecimal theValue = new BigDecimal("4");
    innerList.add(theValue);
    mainList.add(innerList);
}
String jsonString = SomeJsonSerializer.serializeList(mainList);
```

I leave you to pick your favorite date formatter, and your favorite JSON kit.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks a ton. Unfortunately I cannot Upvote you becoz of my reputation points